# Check if all specific values in a matrix exists in a specific order

Tags: matlab

I have several matrices <1x500> with different integers, right now I check if the values I am interested in exists (in this case 30, 40, 50):

```
if any(val == 30) && any(val == 40) && any(val == 50)
```

Then I plot this graph from the matrix and everything works fine, except that I want to change that it should only give true if they occur in the order 30, 40, 50. Right now it only checks if they exist in the matrix any order, it can be 40, 10, 30 and it will give true anyways.

Here is a output of how the matrix could looks like: 0,0,0,0,0,10,50,50,50,50,0,40,40,40,0,0,0,30,30,30 (this shall give false)
0,0,0,0,0,30,30,30,40,40,50,50,50,40,0,0,0,30,30,30 (this shall give true)

I would be very happy if you could help me with this for my hobby project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why you chose to not use `ismember` as I suggested in your last question, but you can use *both* outputs of `ismember` to solve this. First you can use the first output to ensure that all the values appear and use the second output (which is the index of the first occurrence of each value) to determine whether they were in the correct order by comparing the index values to the sorted version of the index values.

```
b = [0,0,0,0,0,30,30,30,40,40,50,50,50,40,0,0,0,30,30,30];

[bool, location] = ismember([30 40 50], b);

present_and_in_order = all(bool) && issorted(location)
%   true
```

Comment: A minor improvement for readability, not sure about speed: present_and_in_order = all(bool) && issorted(location)

Comment: @b3. Thanks for the tip. I always forget about `issorted`.

Comment: This would give `false` for `[50,30,40,50]`. I guess I interpreted the question wrong :-)

Comment: @LuisMendo Yea I agree it was not super clear and there weren't really enough test cases.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the fastest approach, but you can convert the data to a string and use a regular expression:

```
x = [0,0,0,0,0,30,30,30,40,40,50,50,50,40,0,0,0,30,30,30]; % data
v = [30 40 50]; % values in the desired order
xs = mat2str(x); % string that corresponds to x. Numbers are separated by spaces
pattern = strjoin(cellfun(@num2str, num2cell(v), 'uniformoutput', false), ' (.* )*');
    % build pattern for regular expression: numbers from v converted to strings, 
    % separated by a space and then zero or more characters followed by a space,
    % zero or more times
result = ~isempty(regexp(xs, pattern, 'once')); % check if the pattern occurs
```

Note that this would give `true` for something like `x = [0,30,40,30,50,0];` or `x = [50,30,40,50];` as `30`, `40`, `50` are found in that order, possibly with arbitrary numbers in between.